# How to change the default font and size in Notes on El Capitan?

Tags: notes.app, macos

Editing `DefaultFonts.plist` doesn't seem working anymore on the pre-release build 15A279b of El Capitan:

```
sudo vim /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/DefaultFonts.plist
```

It still shows that the file is readonly. I guess it's because the new [System Integrity Protection](http://www.macworld.com/article/2948140/os-x/private-i-el-capitans-system-integrity-protection-will-shift-utilities-functions.html) feature.

Is there another way to change the default font in Notes app?

Comment: `defaults read com.apple.Notes NoteFont` (?)

Answer (score 3):

And the keyboard's plists of PressAll also can no longer be modified to add the new accents.

**Tip:** You do not need to modify the default font and size in Notes.

To change the font, you can select all or one sentence and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

To change the font size, you can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> at the same time to increase or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease the size.

**Another tip:** If you want to use the user font in Notes in OS X, please, install and use [AnyFont](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/anyfont/id821560738?mt=8) in iOS to install your favourite font in iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Gustavo! I do however want to change the default font, because it's troublesome to change the font for every time I create a new note.

Comment: @hujunfeng did you figure out how to change the default font size ? I am having the same problem. Might switch to using evernote because of this.

Comment: @gprasant, no I still don't know how to do it. It might not be possible with El Capitan unfortunately.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question of how to change *default* font.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me on El Capitan:

1.Disable System Integrity Protection

- Restart your mac
- Press and hold CMD+R to boot in recovery
- In the
  menu bar select utilities>terminal
- Type csrutil disable
- Reboot

2.Change font size:

- Fire up the terminal and type in

  cd /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/Resources
- Then

  sudo nano pad.css
- In the editor replace the @[FONT-SIZE] with your font size.
- control+X and then select Y and then return.

Start your notes app and you should see the difference :)

**[EDIT]**

To switch on (or re-activate) SIP, repeat the steps at '1' above. However, instead of using `csrutil disable` in Terminal, use `csrutil enable`.

Comment: Sadly this does not work in Sierra 10.12.6. : (

Comment: ...because Sierra has it in Notes preferences. Finally!

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Pushing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> increments the font size by one point each time.

The default body font size is 12 point. So, if you want to get your notes to be 16 point, just always press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> four times after starting a new  note.

(and go to Format menu, New Notes Start With, and make sure Body is checked)