# Notes App on El Capitan: Change Default Format

Tags: font, notes.app, macos

The Notes app on El Capitan now has a number of styles, such as Body and Heading. How do I change the fonts associated with this?

I tried to make changes to the `DefaultFonts.plist` file, but it appears that the new System Integrity Protection has locked that down. Notes, of course, doesn’t have a preferences setting.

I really don’t like the font that’s showing up, and I don’t want to have to individually change all of my notes.

> Note: This is *not* a duplicate of [How to change the default font and size in Notes on El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205575/how-to-change-the-default-font-and-size-in-notes-on-el-capitan). (a) I am referring to the release version; (b) I want to change the font *styles*; (c) It hasn’t been answered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

But even if the new System Integrity Protection is off, you still will be unable to change it. And the keyboard's plists of PressAndAll also can no longer be modified to add the new accents.

**Tip:** You do not need to modify the default font and size in Notes.

To change the font, you can select all or one sentence and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

To change the font size, you can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> at the same time to increase or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to decrease the size.

**Another tip:** If you want to use the user font in Notes in OS X, please, install and use [AnyFont](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/anyfont/id821560738?mt=8) in iOS to install your favourite font in iOS.