# Change Zoom of Notes.app

Tags: font, notes.app, zoom

I have a 2011 15" MacBook Pro with a higher resolution display (1680 x 1050), an option that was offered back then. Unfortunately, in many of the Apple apps the default 100% zoom level displays normal font sizes (12, 14) way too small to be comfortably read.  In most apps, Pages, Safari, TextEdit etc. I can simply adjust the zoom level, so that the display correctly. However, the Notes app doesn't provide that functionality.

Does anyone know of a hack to change the default zoom level of the Notes app?

I don't want to [change the *font size*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205575/how-to-change-the-default-font-and-size-in-notes-on-el-capitan), i.e., change the font from from 12pt to 16pt as is suggested [elsewhere](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7254823?tstart=0) (and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5518768?tstart=0)) since my notes are synced with the iPad and I don't want them to look too big there.
Nor do I want to change the entire *screen zoom* (accessibility feature).

Rather I am looking for a way to change the size in which the Notes app *displays* the text on OS X.  Any hints much appreciated.

I know that there is no straightforward way to do this, but the Notes.app must get its information for how many pixels to use for a given point size font, for example 16 pixels for a 12 point font from somewhere, no?  That is what I hope to tweak somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default font size by opening the Notes preferences with <kbd>Cmd+comma</kbd> and dragging the slider to the right.
Source: [@howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/266581/how-to-increase-the-font-size-in-macos-notes-app-and-save-your-eyesight/)

Comment: Yes, they've added that functionality finally!