# Keyboard shortcut for monospaced formatting in Notes app

Tags: macos, shortcut, notes.app

Is there any way to define a keyboard shortcut for monospaced formatting in Apples Notes app? Any alternative suggestion to quickly format a single line monospaced without using the mouse?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You can define you own keyboard shortcut.

[image]

You do this in *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > (plus button)*.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Another nice feature of macOS I'm going to use more often in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I currently know is:

Have a previously pre-formatted note which is monospace:

- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> // Copy text style
- Change to your current note
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> // Insert text style

---

There are also some hacky ways - but they didn't work for me on macOS Sierra:

- [How to change the default font and size in Notes on El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205575/how-to-change-the-default-font-and-size-in-notes-on-el-capitan)
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120811055524908

Or you switch to a better note taking app, with more configuration options (and iCloud/Dropbox Sync if you need) - I personally love and use [Quiver](http://happenapps.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this is to go to the Font menu (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), find the font you want to, select its size, etc. and then goto ... (left-top of the font customization window) and click **Add to Favorites**. It will then appear on the Favorites category. If you click this category (on the left side of your font customization window) you'll see it there.

Another pleasant option is that every time you'll open this window you immediately will see your favorite fonts so it's pretty quick I may say.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I did this in notes. CMD T now opens a new note instead of opening formatting.

[image]

Comment: What does your answer have to do with creating monospaced text as the question asks?